# Is it possible to do filebased processing with UDF in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage

I have a UDF defined which does the following with a dataframe where a column contains the location of zip files in azure blob storage(I tested the UDF without spark and that worked out):

1. downloads defined file from the blob and safe it somewhere on the Excutor/Driver
2. Extract a certain file of the blob and safe it on the Excutor/Driver

With this UDF I experience it is the same speed as if I would just loop in python over the files. So is it even possible to do this kind of task in spark? I wanted to use spark to parallelize the download and unzipping to speed it up.
I connected via ssh to the Excutor and the Driver (it is a test cluster, so it only has one of each) and found out that only the data was processe on the Excutor and the driver did not do anything at all. Why is that so?

The next step would be to read the extracted files (normal csvs) to a spark data frame. But how can this be done if the files are distributed over the Excutor and Driver? I did not yet find a way to access the storage of the Excutors. Or is it somehow possible to define a common location within the UDF to write it back to a location at the driver?

I would like to read than the extracted files with:

```
data_frame = (
  spark
    .read
    .format('csv')
    .option('header', True)
    .option('delimiter', ',')  
    .load(f"/mydriverpath/*.csv"))
```

If there is another method to parallelize the download and unzipping of the files I would be happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

PySpark readers / writers make it easy to read and write files in parallel.  When working in Spark, you generally should not loop over files or save data on the driver node.

Suppose you have 100 gzipped CSV files in the `my-bucket/my-folder` directory.  Here's how you can read them into a DataFrame in parallel:

```py
df = spark.read.csv("my-bucket/my-folder")
```

And here's how you can write them to 50 Snappy compressed Parquet files (in parallel):

```py
df.repartition(50).write.parquet("my-bucket/another-folder")
```

The readers / writers do all the heavy lifting for you.  See [here](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4) for more info about `repartition`.

Comment: So with spark.read.csv("my-bucket/my-folder") it will be directly unzipped? So the unfortunate thing is that it is quite a complex structure. The csv is not just directly in the zipped file, but in the zip there is again a zipped file and in that there is more than one folder and different files und only one of the can be used for the analysis and should be read into the dataframe.